# Popup child window with ok and cancel buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've created a simple dialog here with a list of people. All I want to do is a few simple things which are rather trivial in winforms. However I'm struggling to grasp how to do this in wpf with an mvvm approach. Could someone help me out please.

[image]

1. When the user hits the Add New Person button, I want a dialog to appear where a user can type in their Name and either hit OK or Cancel. If the user hits OK, it appends the person to the list. (keep in mind i'll add more edting fields for the users to input, for example last name...)
2. When the users has a single item in the list selected, i want them to give them the ability to click an 'edit' button showing a dialog similar to the one in the previous step, pre populated with the selected items data, so a user can edit the properties. Then depending on if they hit OK or Cancel the changes are committed.

Dropbox solution: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sjpabfod08yil5/AddDeleteItems_basic.zip?dl=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service pattern isn't the only way to implement this, in the following article I show how to do it using the same data-driven mechanism used for regular windows:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM

Comment: This solution of yours do you still use to this day for your projects? At a glance it looks like it will work. So will your solution solve both of my questions?

Comment: Yes, I still use it in all my MVVM projects.

Comment: That is great news. I'll read over more of your article and see how it works. From what I read you mentioned its pretty easy to use so that's great. Other syst es I've looked at are very complex and complicated to use.

Comment: If I have any questions regarding the use of your setup in my projects should I post somewhere specific?  Or contact you somehow ?

Comment: You can post in the comments section of the article if you like but email will probably get a quicker response. I've msg'd you via your web site contact page.

Answer (score 2):

To create and display dialogs using MVVM, you'll want to implement a dialog service pattern to handle such requests. This service would be called from within your view model.

There is a really informative Code Project article about this very topic ([Showing Dialogs When Using The MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern). My advice would be to read that article and then look through the source files accompanying the article. This should provide you with a very good starting point to achieve your use cases (custom dialogs) and can also be used for displaying standard dialogs too (e.g. open file, save file, browse folder etc).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) for you to get started. However, for the dialog [Xceed library](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) has some cool custom controls that may help you.